# Not able to find the shadow element

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Try to get the attribute of a shadow element but get `ElementNotVisibleException Element with CSS input[type='checkbox'] is not present on screen`

```
<checkbox _ngcontent-ebv-c14="" label="User Access" ng-version="8.0.3" class="ng-star-inserted">
  #shadow-root(open)
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="true">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      <!---->
      <span class="label">User Access</span>
   </label>
</checkbox>
```

Using Selenium to get the element attribute

```
WebElement parentElement = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//checkbox[@label='User Access']"));
webdriver.getShadowElement(parentElement,"input[type='checkbox']").getAttribute("value").contains("true");
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can you check if the element is visible or not at the first, before even try to get the attribute

Comment: What website is it from.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem like this way

```
public class test {
    WebDriver driver;
    public WebElement maximizerootelement(WebElement retelement) {
        WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",retelement);
        return retelement;
    }

    @Test
    public void mytest() {
        driver.get("https://yourlin");
        WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("//checkbox[@label='User Access']"));
        WebElement shadowRoot = maximizerootelement(root1);
        String actualHeading = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals("true", actualHeading);


    }
}
```

Using javascript executor your need to expand the element to take action on the element

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by following below steps:

1. Copy the js path from DOM element(go to inspect window-> right click on the element-> click on copy-> click on copy jspath)
2. find the element using javascript executor, convert it to webelement and then perform action needed

WebElement ele =  (IWebElement)executor.ExecuteScript("return Paste your jspath here");
ele.Click();